# React. how to mock api call NOT IN TESTS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

E.g. I have a problem when some endpoints are down or causing errors, but I still need to develop.
I have something like UserService.getUsers I am aware of mocking functions in jest and so on, but I have no idea how I'd better get fake data which I can specify myself.

I thought about a HOC, which redefines functions I need to mock like

`UserService.getUsers=Promise.resolve({});`

But I don't think this is the best way to do this

**NOTE: That's not related to testing stuff**

Comment: I'm assuming UserService.getUsers is an async function, if so when you're receiving the errors, one way would be to return your mocked data in catch. Can you add an example of how UserService.getUsers works?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you're using Webpack, you could use the `resolve` property of the Webpack configuration to alias your imports to some local mocked version.

https://webpack.js.org/configuration/resolve/

For example, if you had some import like this:

```
import UserService from 'some-package-or-path';

const myData = UserService.getUsers();
```

You can alias `some-package-or-path` to a local file:

```
// webpack.config.js
const path = require('path');

module.exports = {
  //...
  resolve: {
    alias: {
     'some-package-or-path': path.resolve(__dirname, 'src/mocks/userServiceMock'),
    },
  },
};

// userServiceMock index.js
const mock = {
  getUserData: () => {
    return {
      mockedDataProperties: 'whatever'
    }
  }
};

export default mock;
```

Obviously your implementation will differ a bit but that's the gist of it.